# PostgreSQL now() function not returning time

Tags: postgresql

When inserting `now()` in a table, the written value only contains the date (e.g. 2017-12-20), but not the date *and* time as specified in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html).

See this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7230d/1).

```
create table timetest (
    id serial primary key,
    mydate date
);

insert into timetest (mydate) values (
now());
```

Is there some specific command that should be passed to either write or retrieve also the time information?

Comment: Use [`TIMESTAMP / "DATETIME"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) for the column type. The value is being *truncated* to fit in the `DATE`-ONLY field. Also, to check the hypothesis that "now() is not returning the time": `select now() as n`.

Comment: `mydate date` --- you declared a field as a `date`, it does not have time fraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created `mydate date` as a `date` type column. `date` only represents the date fraction (unsurprisingly).

If you need both date and time use `timestamp` type instead.

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html